# Поиск количества наименьших в диапазоне

Tags: c++

Помогите найти способ поиска количества наименьших чисел.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Сума цифр числа
int allsum(int num){
    int asum = 0;
    while(num>0){
        asum += num%10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return asum;
}
//Перевіряє в якому діапазоні число і знаходить суму цифр
int check(int i){
    int sum = 0;
    if( 0 <= i && i <= 9) sum = i;
        else if( 10 <= i && i <= 99) sum = i%10 + i/10;
            else if( 100 <= i && i <= 999) sum = allsum(i);
                else if( 1000 <= i && i <= 9999) sum = allsum(i);
                    else if( 10000 <= i && i <= 99999) sum = allsum(i);
                        else if( 100000 <= i && i <= 999999) sum = allsum(i);
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    int m,n,count = 0;
    cin >> m >> n;

    for(m;m<=n;m++){

        if(check(m)==1)count++;
    }

    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Минимальная сумма цифр
>
> Сколько натуральных чисел из промежутка [M,N] имеют наименьшую сумму
>   цифр ?
>
> Входные данне
>
> Во входном файле два числа M и N (1 ≤ M ≤ N ≤ 1000000) .
>
> Выходные данне
>
> В выходной файл нужно записать ответ - одно число.

Comment: Ну, вы уже записали в выходной файл ответ "одно число"?:)

Comment: А зачем вам столько одинаковых вызовов `allsum()`? То есть чем отличаются вызовы этой функции для `42` и `123456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сэкономил на том, что проверять входные данные не нужно - они гарантируются, и что нет смысла считать сумму, если она уже превысила минимум...

```
int sum(int n, int min)
{
    int s = 0;
    while(n)
    {
        s += n%10;
        if (s > min) return s; // На максимальном диапазоне эта проверка
                               // ускоряет счет примерно в 3 раза.
        n/=10;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int m, n, min = 100000, count = 0;
    cin >> m >> n;
    for(;m <= n;++m)
    {
        int s = sum(m,min);
        if (s == min) count++;
        else if (s < min) {
            min = s;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял почему min = 100000?

Comment: Да что угодно, большее 9*6=54.

Answer (score 0):

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая подсчитывает число чисел с наименьшей суммой цифр в заданном диапазоне. В ней диапазон вводится с консоли и результат никуда кроме консоли не выводится.

На основе этой демонстрационной программы вы можете написать свою программу, которая считывает данные из файла и записывает результат в файл.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

unsigned int sum_of_digits( unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    do { sum += x % Base; } while ( x /= Base );

    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a range of positive numbers m and n (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int m, n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> m >> n ) or ( m == 0 or n == 0 ) ) break;

        if ( n < m ) std::swap( m, n );

        unsigned int min_sum = 0;
        unsigned int count   = 0;

        for ( unsigned int i = m; not ( n < i ); i++ )
        {
            unsigned int sum = sum_of_digits( i );

            if ( i == m or sum < min_sum )
            {
                min_sum = sum;
                count = 1;
            }
            else if ( sum == min_sum )
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\nThere are " << count << " numbers " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "with minimum sum of digits equal to " << min_sum << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог с программой может выглядеть, например, следующим образом.

```
Enter a range of positive numbers m and n (0-exit): 1 100

There are 3 numbers 
with minimum sum of digits equal to 1
Enter a range of positive numbers m and n (0-exit): 0
```

Comment: Позволю себе заметить, что ваш код не выдерживает стиль `not` и `or` до конца :), но хуже - что он дает неверный результат. Между 1 и 100 включительно имеется **три** числа с минимальной суммой цифр, равной 1: `1`, `10`, `100`...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, Просто была опечатка, вместо  Вместо count = 0 должно быть count = 1 в if предложении.